# Sartre on amorality and his influence on Vargas Llosa?

Tags: jean-paul-sartre, mario-vargas-llosa

I noticed Vargas Llosa credits Sartre with his characters being amoral. I'm wondering when does Sartre write about amorality? About characters not facing repercusions for their amoral acts.

I'm very curious since in most western movies, even if there's not clear divide between good and evil. The characters do face repercussions for being amoral.

Comment: Can you quote the text where Vargas Llosa credits Sartre?

Comment: He mentions him in interviews. But here's the quote of a scholar reviewing the novel ". The epigraph taken from Sartre  in the novel seems justified by the boys‘ stories: ―We play the part of heroes because we‘re  cowards,  the  part  of  saints  because  we‘re  wicked:  we  play  the killer‘s role because we‘re dying to murder our fellow man: we play at being because we‘re liars from the moment we‘re born."                                                                                                        f

Comment: Are you looking for the origin of that quote? It's from Act II of *Kean*: "On joue les héros parce qu'on est lâche et les saints parce qu'on est méchant; on joue les assassins parce qu'on meurt d'envie de tuer son prochain, on joue parce qu'on est menteur de naissance."

Comment: Nice, well I'm interested in Sartre's ideas on morality. I'm wondering if there's a good intro to learn more about his ethics. In Vargas Llosa's book, "Time of the hero" the main Jaguar commits a crime and goes unpunished. Vargas Llosa said that his ideas on morality came about from reading Sartre.